# can't get example 'C' code for BLE from web site for Silicon Labs thunderboard

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Bought thunderboard, card in its box says go to:  [www.silabs.com/start-thunderboard](http://www.silabs.com/start-thunderboard)
but I get good old:   "Error 404 -- Not Found"

So I ran Simplicity Studio 4 with the Tboard plugged in to my laptop.
But SS4 doesn't detect the Tboard.

I'm trying to get example 'C' code for doing BLE -- specifically, for Gatt reads and writes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the out of the box documentation [here](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/training/wireless/bg22-thunderboard-workshop-out-of-the-box-thunderboard-example-project.pdf). For more useful info on using Thunderboard, see the links below:-

- [Bluetooth workshop: Develop on a BG22 thunderboard kit](https://www.silabs.com/support/training/develop-a-secure-iot-device-on-a-bg22-thunderboard-kit/bg22-overview)
- [Getting started with Silicon Labs BG22 chipset](https://www.novelbits.io/getting-started-silicon-labs-bg22/)
- [Thunderboard BG22 West Side Electronics](http://westsideelectronics.com/thunderboard-bg22/)

Regarding the board detection, check that you can see a COMPORT in the Device Manager. If not, I would try it on a different PC and if it still isn't detect then I would contact support [here](https://www.silabs.com/support).